# Could not connect to development server on Android emulator Windows OS?

Tags: android, react-native

[image]

[image]

I am unable to solve this issue for 3 days. The same source runs fine in iOS App (Mac System ofcourse). But gets this error when I try to run in Android emulator

I have tried most of the solutions available in the internet.

1 - Dev Settings -> Adding the local ip

2 - Cleaned npm (removed node_modules and installed npm again)

3 - uninstalled npm globally and reinstalled

4 - That useless adb commands also tried

When I run, *npm run start* 
[image]

***When go to my local ip (192.168.1.61:8081) in browser, i get to know React Package manager is not running.***

Answer (score 1):

Turn ON the mobile data on your android emulator. This might solve the issue.